# Reference files from one repository to another

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a git repository with a lot of source files. I would like to create a new repository, where some of the files from the existing repository is referenced into the new repository.

**Example:**

Repository A contains:

- Directory 1

  - Source file 1
  - Source file 2
- Directory 2

  - Source file 3
  - Source file 4

In Repository B I would like to reference source file 3 from Repository A:

- Directory 3

  - Source file 5
  - Source file 3 from Repository A.

Repository B is going to be shared among developers who do not all have access to Repository A.

So my question is: Is it possible to reference some files from one repository to another, such that when developers with access to Respository A changes the original file the changes will be discovered by Repository B? If it is possible, how can I do it?

Comment: You could consider using [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). The discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196312/how-to-setup-a-git-repository-where-different-users-can-only-see-certain-parts) might also be relevant to you.

Comment: I am interested in referencing single files from repository A. As far as I can see the submodules only works for entire repositories.

Comment: @ThomasCle correct: submodules only work on entire repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Git thinks of files as the content of the whole repository, not as a collection of files. Therefore this is quite hard to do. If this feature is critical I suggest you switch to a file-centric SCM system.

However it is possible, but quite clumsy.

create an orphan branch in repo B with the file you want to track. Merge this file into an other branch in repo B, for example the master branch, possible using the subtree-merge algoritm.

You can use gitolite to restrict access to one branch from your repo. Now you can add repo B to repo A with as a submodule or as a remote and doing a subtree merge. (you can read more about how to handle submodules and subtree merges on git-scm.com).

However, you cannot use gitolite to deny reads from the whole repo B, just write access. If you're looking for read prevention as well, you'll need to put the file in a repo C

Answer (score 0):

The solution we use at work to share code between repos is to put the shared code in a NuGet package. Then that package can be consumed from any repo and you don't have to do any wonky git setups and you keep access controls as they should be.