# Restricting access to users

Tags: git, version-control, repository, access-control

I already know that in Git there is no support for restricting access to specific folders.

I've read an article that stated that big companies like *Yahoo!*, *Google* and a lot more used **Git** (along with few other *SVCs*).

So my question is the following: how do big companies like those I mentioned before handle developers permissions? I highly doubt designers can access developers code and viceversa.
The possible solutions I have found are:

- Making a repository for every job
- Git *submodules*
- Hooks

What are the advantages of each of them and which ones are used more widely?

Answer (score 0):

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196312/how-to-setup-a-git-repository-where-different-users-can-only-see-certain-parts) was asked already but here are my thoughts.

I think the best way is to create a separate repository for every application or even module(s) if it makes sense.
Submodules only needed if you want to use the same git repository in other repositories otherwise it just complicates your workflow but you can use it for access control as well.
You can do a lot of things with hooks but you can't restrict read access with it only write access. If the user can access the repository he gets a clone of it. See [Git access control](http://www.peterlundgren.com/blog/on-gits-shortcomings/#access-control). Of course you don't have to write these hooks yourself, these are already in most of the servers available for git.

Comment: What if I want to give only access to css sub-folder? Would I need to make a repository with only css folder content?